# GoogleMapsEvent vs google.maps.event

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am in the process of upgrading from `Ionic 2 beta` to `RC3`. In doing so, I also update the version of Google Maps to `"google-maps": "^3.2.1"`. The Change in Google Maps, is that now it uses a `GoogleMap` object instead of `google.maps.Map` ([see here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/)).

I have been using `google.maps.event.`, but now need to update it to use `GoogleMapsEvent` (I think). Because I get the following error on `ionic serve`:

> Cannot find name 'google'.

```
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(that.map, 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
      let position: CameraPosition = that.map.getCameraPosition();
      let zoom: number = position.zoom;
      setTimeout(function () {
        // let center: GoogleMapsLatLng = that.map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(that.map, 'resize');
        // that.map.setCenter(center);
        that.map.setZoom(zoom);
      }, 100);
    });
```

But `GoogleMapsEvent` does not have a `addListenerOnce` or `trigger` method.

**Question**

How do I update the code above to use `GoogleMapsEvent` instead of `google.maps.event`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/), this is how you can add eventlisteners.

```
 // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
 let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

 let map = new GoogleMap(element);

 // listen to MAP_READY event
 map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => console.log('Map is ready!'));
```